# prove by induction that every finite nonempty set of reals has a minimum.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Exercise on *Mathematical Induction* is from **Mathematics for Computer Science** by Albert R. Meyer, Eric Lehman, and Frank Thomson Leighton. It says,

> Prove by induction that every nonempty finite set of real numbers has a minimum element.

I rephrased it in the following way to make induction variable explicit.

> Let $S_n$ denote the set of $n$ real numbers.
>    Theorem: Every nonempty $S_n$ has a smallest element.
> Proof. By ordinary induction. Let induction hypothesis $P(n)::=$ in any set $S_n$, containing $n$ real numbers, $\exists m \in S_n: \forall s \in S_n: m \leq s$. Prove $P(n)$ holds for all $n \geq 1$.
>  Base case ($n=1$): $P(1)$ is obviously true. If we choose $m$ to be that single element of $S_n$, then it's simply less than or equal to itself. Therefore, $P(1)$ holds.
>   Inductive step: Suppose $P(n)$ holds for some $n \geq 1$. Show that $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$.
>    Since $P(n)$ holds, we can conclude there exists $m \in S_n$ such that $\forall s \in S_n: m \leq s$. Since $P(n)$ holds for **any** set containing $n$ real numbers, it must be hold for the first $n$ elements of $S_n$. That is, there exists an element $m$ smaller than all of the first $n$ elements. We just need to compare $m$ to the (n+1)th element of $S_{n+1}$ and take the minimum of these two as new $m$, which proves $P(n+1)$.
>   We can conclude by induction principle $p(n)$ holds for all $n \in N$.

Note: $N::= \{1,2,...\}$
 I've doubt on the proof and structure of this induction proof. I know its inductive part is a bit wordy. I didn't use set notations to write, instead tried to explain it in this way. Is this way of proving acceptable? I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. “Let $S_n$ denote the set of $n$ real numbers.” It makes no sense, since there are infinitely many such sets.
2. “Theorem: Every nonempty $S_n$ has a smallest element.” The statement should be that every finite and non-empty set of real numbers has a smallest element.
3. You write as if you were working on *one* set $S_n$ with $n$ elements and *one* set $S_{n+1}$ with $n+1$ elements. You can do it as follows: let $S$ be a set with $n+1$ elements. Take $m\in S$. If $m$ is the smallest element of $S$, you're done. otherwise, let $S'=S\setminus\{m\}$. The $S'$ has $n$ elements and therefore, by the induction hypothesis, it has a smallest element $m'$. Since $m$ is *not* the smallest element of $S$, $m'\leqslant m$ and, for each $k\in S'$, $m'\leqslant k$. Therefore, $m'$ is the smallest element of $S$.